# Applying custom Jquery UI resize handles on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have the following code to enable custom resize handles on an image. I tried the code on a `div` element which is working fine. But on `img` element it is not working.

and will give the following error.

`uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined jquery ui resize`

What i understood is that the custom handles should be children of the element that is to be resized. Is there a way to add custom handles on image and resize it ?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#img-wrapper img').resizable({
    handles: {
        'nw': '#nwgrip',
        'ne': '#negrip',
        'sw': '#swgrip',
        'se': '#segrip',
        'n': '#ngrip',
        'e': '#egrip',
        's': '#sgrip',
        'w': '#wgrip'
    }
});
});
```

```css
#img-wrapper{
position:relative;
  width:350px;
  height:150px;
  }

#nwgrip, #negrip, #swgrip, #segrip, #ngrip, #egrip, #sgrip, #wgrip {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
  position:absolute;
}
#nwgrip {
    left: -5px;
    top: -5px;
}
#negrip{
     top: -5px;
     right: -5px;
}
#swgrip{
    bottom: -5px;
    left: -5px;
}
#segrip{
     bottom: -5px;
    right:-5px;
}
#ngrip{
     top: -5px;
    left:50%;
}
#sgrip{
     bottom: -5px;
    left: 50%;
}
#wgrip{
     left:-5px;
     top:50%;
}
#egrip{
     right:-5px;
     top:50%;
}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNjb53/rY+WmG+4L6tTl9m6PpqknWZvRt0rO1SRnJzw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="img-wrapper">
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" id="nwgrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" id="negrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" id="swgrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se" id="segrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" id="ngrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" id="sgrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" id="egrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" id="wgrip"></div>
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [alsoResize](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-alsoResize).

If you need to preserve the aspect ratio add [aspectRatio: true](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-aspectRatio).

Therefore, change from:

```
$('#img-wrapper img').resizable({
```

to:

```
$('#img-wrapper').resizable({
```

My snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#img-wrapper').resizable({
    handles: {
      'nw': '#nwgrip',
      'ne': '#negrip',
      'sw': '#swgrip',
      'se': '#segrip',
      'n': '#ngrip',
      'e': '#egrip',
      's': '#sgrip',
      'w': '#wgrip'
    },
    alsoResize: $(this).find('img')
  });
});
```

```css
#img-wrapper{
  position:relative;
  width:350px;
  height:150px;
  }

#nwgrip, #negrip, #swgrip, #segrip, #ngrip, #egrip, #sgrip, #wgrip {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
  position:absolute;
}
#nwgrip {
    left: -5px;
    top: -5px;
}
#negrip{
     top: -5px;
     right: -5px;
}
#swgrip{
    bottom: -5px;
    left: -5px;
}
#segrip{
     bottom: -5px;
    right:-5px;
}
#ngrip{
     top: -5px;
    left:50%;
}
#sgrip{
     bottom: -5px;
    left: 50%;
}
#wgrip{
     left:-5px;
     top:50%;
}
#egrip{
     right:-5px;
     top:50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="img-wrapper">
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" id="nwgrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" id="negrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" id="swgrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se" id="segrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" id="ngrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" id="sgrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" id="egrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" id="wgrip"></div>
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150">
</div>
```